# $f'(x) = f(x-1)$ then $f$ is not bounded

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, delay-differential-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Then consider the following delay equation : 
$$f'(x) = f(x-1)$$

Let $S$ be the set of solution ot this equation. Then I would like to prove that :

$\forall f \in S -\{ x \mapsto 0\}$, $f$ is not bounded.

What I've done so far is that :

The set of solutions is an infinite dimensional space, hence it's hard to get a general form of all solutions, hence I don't think that calculating the characteristic equation is a good idea.

I've noticed that this is true for all equations of the form : $f'(x) = f(x-a)$ where $-1 \leq a \leq 1$. 
Yet this is not true for $a = 3\pi/2$, because $x \mapsto \sin(x)$ is a trivial solution and clearly $x \mapsto \sin(x)$ is bounded.

Maybe using the mean value is a good idea, in order to get a contradiction if we suppose that $f$ is bounded. But the problem with this approach is that I don't get enough informations on $a$.

We also have the formula : 
$$f^{(n)}(x) = f(x-n)$$

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

**AN IDEA**

If $f$ is a tempered distributional solution, taking the Fourier transform, 
$$
i\xi\hat{f}(\xi)=e^{i a \xi}\hat{f}(\xi), $$ 
so $\hat{f}$ must be supported at $\xi=\pm 1$, and this is only possible if $\pm i=e^{ia}$. (Thanks LutzL for correcting the previous version of this).

Notice that the only non-zero distributions that are supported at a point are the Dirac delta and its derivatives. This corresponds to the $f=\sin$ solution you found above: notice that the Fourier transform of $\sin$ is 
$$
\mathcal F(\sin)(\xi)=\frac{\pi}{i}(\delta(\xi-1)-\delta(\xi+1)).$$

Therefore, either the solution is of this kind, or it is not a tempered distribution, and so, in particular, it is not a bounded function.

Comment: You mean $iξ\hat f(ξ)=e^{iaξ}\hat f(ξ)$ which leads to the the first restriction of the support to $ξ=\pm 1$ and thus $\pm i=e^{\pm ia}$.

Comment: @LutzL: you are surely right, I wrote in a hurry and I see that my post is not self-consistent, as $\mathcal F(\sin)$ is not supported in $\xi=0$. I will come back on this when I have some time. I hope that the idea is clear, at least.